# My numbers appear as old style numbers in cursive mode

Tags: oldstylenums

How can I change from old style numbers to normal looking numbers when using cursive modes such as \emph ? My problem occurs when I try to make a reference using the style=chem-acs package, because the numbers does not in any way look like the ones in prober articles.
Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\usepackage[journal=rsc]{chemstyle}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{dblfnote}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\em{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}
\end{document}
```

[image: Numbers I get from my code]

Comment: I have now updated my problem with the result.

Comment: Umm, the numerals shown in the screenshot are lining numerals, *not* old-style numerals.

Comment: Is that really the normal look of numbers cause that is not how they display them in chemistry articles in JACS?

Comment: `\em{1 2}` is incorrect syntax. Anyway, you're telling TeX to print numbers in italics.

Comment: Is that why they look odd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be some terminological confusion over numeral **style** -- "lining" versus "oldstyle" on the one hand and numeral **shape** -- "upright" versus "italic" -- on the other. Style and shape are two separate and (in principle) independent aspects.

The following table, which loads the `cfr-lm` package for its `\ostyle` and `\lstyle` macros, shows the shapes and styles of the numerals in a 2x2 table:

[image]

Observe that the numerals shown in your screenshot are lining numerals, *not* oldstyle numbers.

If you absolutely, positively can't stand the look of Computer Modern's italic numerals, you may need to start thinking about employing a different font family for your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm,booktabs}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
font shape   & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{numeral style}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
             & lining & oldstyle \\
\midrule
upright      &\lstyle{0123456789}    &    \ostyle{0123456789}\\
italic       &\em\lstyle{0123456789} & \em\ostyle{0123456789}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```